# Cannot create custom Appender for log4j2 in scala

Tags: scala, log4j, log4j2

I try to create a custom Appender in Scala (to use it in UTs), to migrate log4j1 to log4j2, but i cannot.

in log4j1 it's like:

```
class TestAppender extends AppenderSkeleton {

}
```

now i'm doing somting like:

```
class TestAppender extends AbstractAppender {

}
```

but i get

```
Cannot resolve overloaded constructor `AbstractAppender`
```

Any thoughts on how to do so?

Comment: It seems you need to pass something to the constructor of that class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java, you call the superclass constructor in your constructor with `super(arguments)`.  In Scala, however, because the body of the class (excluding `def`s) is the default constructor for the class, the superclass constructor is called by passing the arguments in the `extends` clause:

```scala
class TestAppender extends AbstractAppender(...) {
```

Since the only non-deprecated constructor for `AbstractAppender` appears to be [this one](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/appender/AbstractAppender.html#AbstractAppender-java.lang.String-org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Filter-org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Layout-boolean-org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Property:A-), you almost certainly want something like:

```scala
class TestAppender extends AbstractAppender("test", someFilter, someLayout, whetherToIgnoreExceptions, Array()) {
```

If you want to allow the user of your class to specify a parameter for `AbstractAppender`, then you would do something like:

```scala
class TestAppender(ignoreExceptions: Boolean) extends AbstractAppender("test", someFilter, someLayout, ignoreExceptions, Array()) {
```